# ADO.NET retry of transaction within one sql connection

Tags: c#, t-sql, transactions, ado.net

I try to implement simple retry logic using ADO.NET and transactions.
A sample of code:

```
        using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(m_connection))
        {
            conn.Open();

            bool committed = false;
            Exception exception = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < s_attempts; i++)
            {
                SqlTransaction tran = conn.BeginTransaction();
                try
                {
                    // different commands here..

                    tran.Commit();
                    committed = true;
                    break;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    exception = ex;
                    tran.Rollback();
                }
            }

            if (!committed && exception != null)
            {
                throw exception;
            }
        }
```

Is it okay to create another transaction within one connection after the previous one was rollbacked?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: @Anderi ,it depends on the purpose ,if one transaction is depenedent on another then those two transactions must be in in single commit else better to loosely couple them.

Comment: @HameedSyed, in try section I want to call the same logic each time. Sometimes it crashes (with deadlock for example) and I want to roll back that was already done and retry the same command again in a new transaction. As I understand from your answer I can do it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason why you can't continue to create transactions on the same connection, provided all transactions are either committed or rolled back.

I would question why the first attempt failed though, I'm assuming you'll put some delay (possibly incrementing) between each attempt to commit the transaction.

Comment: In most cases, it is a protection from deadlocks which occur rarely. I thought in the same way but was not entirely sure. Thank you for the answer!